# OpenCV et Android

Tags: android, opencv

I have downloaded opencv examples and i want to run the ndk example which use the opencv library

i get this error : Android NDK: ERROR:/home/user/Bureau/OpenCV/samples/tutorial-3-native/jni/Android.mk:opencv_contrib: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that /home/user/Bureau/GL5/Android/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/user/share/OpenCV/../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_contrib.a exists  or that its path is correct

I have tested a simple Ndk projet and it works

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problems but if you are running the built-in samples, I believe you have checked out the following links:

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html

These work just as the way they are described. If you are running your own custom opencv-android app, you will have to point to the .mk file in opencv-android project and also define opencv home variable in .bashrc or windows environment variables.